# Determine 'w' and 'b' in hard margin SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, linear

I have been asked the following question related to SVM (Hard Margin) in the exam, and I failed to answer it. Can anyone help me find the solution?

Consider the dataset **M**:

\begin{align*}
& \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T, 1\right), \\
& \left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}^T, 1\right), \\
& \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}^T, -1\right), \\
& \left(\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T, -1\right)
\end{align*}

My approach was to sketch it and draw the marginal plane, then identify support vectors using my intuition (looking at the sketch). After that, I created a hyperplane that was the midpoint of both marginal planes and found its slope and y-intercept, but still, my answer was wrong.
I am very new to machine learning so any help would be appreciated. I also tried the solution with sklearn library and the values of **w = [-2  2] and b = 3**

This is something similar but it didn't work in my case: [Support Vector Machine - Calculate w by hand](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353552/support-vector-machine-calculate-w-by-hand).
[image]

Comment: I added an answer at your linked post that might help. If not, clarify here how far you got following those methods and where you get stuck.

Comment: (If so, close this as a duplicate of that.)

Comment: @BenReiniger First, thank you so much for your answer. Second, in that question, he already has a hyperplane in the diagram. By just looking at it, he tries to find 'w' and 'b' using the equation of the line. But in my case, I want to figure out these values by drawing the marginal plane. With your method, I can find 'w', but I am still confused about how to find 'b'. Sorry, I am new to this domain.

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by "marginal plane"? Could you sketch the four points together with what you find challenging to quantify?

Comment: @BenReiniger Marginal planes are the decision boundaries, the distance between the hyperplane, and the observations closest to the hyperplane (support vectors) or you can refer to them as the maximum margin classifier. Ok, I will update the question with the plot.

Comment: @BenReiniger The plot picture is uploaded. This is what I drew just by identifying the support vectors. Now, I have to figure out how to draw the hyperplane. I already mentioned my approach in my question. Maybe from here, you can guide me on how to proceed further and find 'w' and 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

I see two main ways to do this:

(1) Follow the steps of [Support Vector Machine - Calculate w by hand.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353552/support-vector-machine-calculate-w-by-hand), from which the solution follows. In summary, we use the property that the decision boundary is of the form $\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{x} + b = 0$, and use inspection to guess initial values of the parameters. Then, we use the invariance of our guesses to positive scaling plus the fact that the width between support vectors (orthogonal distance between the parallel hyperplanes containing the support vectors for class +1 and -1) is expressible as a function of $\mathbf{w}$.

First, by inspection, we know that the true decision boundary is parallel to the line $x_2 = x_1 - \frac{3}{2}$. We know that the true $\mathbf{w}, b$ should have the property that $\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{x} + b = 0$, we reach the initial guess $\tilde{\mathbf{w}} = [-1, 1], \tilde{b} = \frac{3}{2}$. However, for any $c > 0$, note that we could potentially have a decision boundary with parameters $c\tilde{\mathbf{w}} = [-c, c], c\tilde{b} = 3c / 2$, such that $\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{x} + b = 0$.

The [linked answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353552/support-vector-machine-calculate-w-by-hand) then uses the fact that the "width" (the size of the margin on either side of the decision boundary) between the support vectors is $2 / \lVert w \rVert$, for which you can find the derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305925/why-is-the-svm-margin-equal-to-frac2-mathbfw). By inspection, in your problem setting, the "width" between the support vectors is $1 / \sqrt{2}$.

Given the constraint that $1 / \sqrt{2} = 2 / \lVert w \rVert$, it suffices to find the value of $c$ such that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2}{c \lVert \tilde{w} \rVert}$$
holds. Some simple algebra shows that $c = 2$, from which $\mathbf{w} = [-2, 2], b = 3$ result as desired.

(2) Identify support vectors by inspection. Then, use the fact that for support vectors, $\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{x} + b = y$ as a consequence of the SVM objective, where $y \in \{-1, 1\}$, to develop a system of equations.

Anyway, by inspection, all four of the points you listed are support vectors, yielding the system of equations:
$$w_1 + b = 1$$
$$-w_2 + b = 1$$
$$w_1 - w_2  + b = -1$$
$$2w_1 + b = -1$$

and some algebra yields your desired $\mathbf{w}, b$.